# Node CSV Parser output issue

Tags: parsing, node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose

I am trying to use Node CSV Parser to read in a query result from my Mongo database and write it out to a csv file.

When I run my script, I get a csv file with two [object] entries on the first line and everything else blank.

This is my code:

```
// node samples/sample.js
var csv = require('csv');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var User = require('../models/userModel').User;

dsn = "mongodb://localhost/test";

mongoose.connect(dsn);

console.log ("here");

var users = User.find({}, function(err, result){
        console.log(result);
        });
var columns = ['userName','agencyName','email','password','id']; 

csv()
.from(users, {
    columns: true
    })
.toPath(__dirname+'/users.csv',{
    columns: ['userName','agencyName','email','password','id']
    })
.transform(function(data){
    data.unshift(data.pop());
    return data;
})
.on('data',function(data,index){
    console.log('#'+index+' '+JSON.stringify(data));
})
.on('end',function(count){
    console.log('Number of lines: '+count);  
})
.on('error',function(error){
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

This is the data displayed in terminal:

```
[ { userName: 'LasVegas',
    agencyName: 'City of Las Vegas',
    email: 'lasvegas@gmail.com',
    password: 'upload1',
    _id: 4ffe2e6bddc0c02b15000001 } ]
```

I have only entered one user into the database so I believe it is correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is my code after trying to call csv in the callback:

```
// node samples/sample.js
var csv = require('csv');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var User = require('../models/userModel').User;

dsn = "mongodb://localhost/test";

mongoose.connect(dsn);

console.log ("here");

var columns = ['userName','agencyName','email','password','id']; 

var users = User.find({}, function(err, result){
    console.log(result);

if (err){
    callback(err,null);
}else{

csv()
.from(users, {
columns: true
})
.toPath(__dirname+'/users.csv',{
columns: ['userName','agencyName','email','password','id']
})
.transform(function(data){
data.unshift(data.pop());
return data; 
})
.on('data',function(data,index){
console.log('#'+index+' '+JSON.stringify(data));
})
.on('end',function(count){
console.log('Number of lines: '+count);
})
.on('error',function(error){
console.log(error.message);
})
}
});
```

Now instead of two [object] fields, the fields contain weird symbols and I am asked to choose a filter when opening the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `User.find()` is asynchronous; it's not assigning the results of the search to `users`. You need to move your call to `csv` into the callback and either replace the reference to `users` there with `results` or rename the callback parameter to `users`.

Comment: I think I successfully moved the call to csv to the callback but my output still is not right.

Comment: Figured it out and got everything to work correctly. Thanks again for all of your help.